# Creating a view based on 2 json fields

Tags: mysql, sql

in our system we have 11 criteria (id 1..11)

We have a table in MySQL 5.6, in this table there is a text columns that contains JSon objects:

criteria column example:

```
[
  {
    "important": false,
    "paramsJson": {
      "items": [
        {
          "text": "asd"
        },
        {
          "text": "fasf"
        },
      ]
    },
    "criteria": 1
  },
  {
    "important": true,
    "paramsJson": {
      "A": "X",
      "B": "Y",
      "C": 2
    },
    "criteria": 11
  },
  {
    "important": false,
    "paramsJson": {
      "ASD": true,
      "WERT": true,
    },
    "criteria": 10
  }
]
```

the format is "important" attribute first, then a "paramsJson" that can contains complex object and in the end the "criteria" id.
we can have up to all 11 criteria in any order.

**Now i want to create a view with important column for each criteria**
so we will have 11 columns important1, ..., important11. each column can be null/true/false.

In the json example above the entry will have important1=false, important10=false and important11=true (the rest are null).

would appreciate your help with suggestions on how to extract the important attribute from the criteria column and attach it the the cirteria id that follows.

Thanks

Comment: If you are going to be using the data in your JSON objects in queries, you really should decompose that data into a set of relational tables in the First Normal Form. Doing what you want with the data the way it is will be really expensive.

Comment: Maybe consider to you MongoDB or any other document oriented database instead of using MySql. Choose the right tool for your needs, you don't need always use hammer.

Comment: that's clear to us, we will migrate our data but it will take time as this is not a priority, for now all we need is to create a temporary report.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [MySQL JSON UDFs](https://blogs.oracle.com/svetasmirnova/entry/json_udf_functions_0_4), which include a `JSON_EXTRACT()` function that you can use to extract JSON objects and elements from your strings stored in MySQL. You may want to read my [blog post](http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2014/02/14/faster-json-parsing-using-mysql-json-udfs/) for instructions on installing the UDFs. The latest version can be dowloaded [here](http://downloads.mysql.com/snapshots/pb/mysql-json-udfs-0.4.0/mysql-json-udfs-0.4.0-labs-json-udfs-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64.tar.gz).

If you upgrade to MySQL 5.7, then you can use the [native JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html) in your view, and you would also have the option to add [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) to your table to expose the extracted JSON values if you want.

Comment: i have read about the 5.7 capabilities but i am afraid upgrading is not an option at the moment. i will try the other tool that you suggested. thanks

Comment: i was looking at your blog and it seems that the json_extract function is pretty basic, (i was using the locate function with other simpler cases i had). how do you see it coming handy with the problem i presented?